# Blocking lines of length $5$ in a $7 \times 8$ matrix; how can we know the solutions have a specific form?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, puzzle

A friend shared with me the following puzzle he encountered in a Chinese math competition:

> In a $7 \times 8$ matrix, we place tokens so that any straight line of length $5$ (horizontal, vertical, or on either diagonal) intersects at least one token.  What is the smallest number of tokens required?

*I'm not asking for a solution to this problem.*  I know the solution, I want to know the following:

> *Q*: I found, by computation, the possible solutions all have a particular form (I list them below).  Can we prove this? (In a way other than "I tried all the other possibilities".)

To illustrate the problem,

- This arrangement doesn't work
  $$\begin{array}{|ccccccc|}
  \hline
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \cdot & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \hline
  \end{array}$$
  since e.g. there is the line
  $$\begin{array}{|ccccccc|}
  \hline
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \square & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \square & \bullet & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \square & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \square & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \square & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \hline
  \end{array}.$$
- This arrangement works
  $$\begin{array}{|ccccccc|}
  \hline
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \hline
  \end{array}$$
  and uses $14$ tokens (which is not the minimum).

The solutions are (**spoiler alert**):

> It requires $11$ tokens, realized by these matrices: $\begin{array}{cc} \begin{array}{|ccccccc|} \hline \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \hline \end{array} & \begin{array}{|ccccccc|} \hline \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \hline \end{array} \\ \begin{array}{|ccccccc|} \hline \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \hline \end{array} & \begin{array}{|ccccccc|} \hline \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \hline \end{array} \\ \begin{array}{|ccccccc|} \hline \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \hline \end{array} & \begin{array}{|ccccccc|} \hline \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \hline \end{array} \\ \begin{array}{|ccccccc|} \hline \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \hline \end{array} & \begin{array}{|ccccccc|} \hline \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot & \bullet & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \bullet \\ \hline \end{array} \\ \end{array}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Part 1.**

Prove that **it is impossible to place $10$ tokens**.

Let's try to build with $10$ tokens.

First, note that in each column/row must be at least $1$ token.

Lets call column with token in $1$st cell as column $a$; and row with token in $2$nd cell as column $b$.

Column $a$ and column $b$ must have at least $2$ tokens.

Column $a$ must have cells $1,6$ with tokens; column $b$ must have cells $2,7$ with tokens. (otherwise we'll need to have third column with multiple tokens: more then $10$ tokens at total).

If we want to use only $10$ tokens, then columns $a$ and $b$ need to be placed as $4$th and $5$th columns (otherwise red $5$-rows need to have at least $1$ token, that derives other column $a'$ or $b'$).

[image]

Then we have to place $6$ tokens in two $3\times 3$ green squares:

[image]

Each $3\times 3$ square must have $3$ tokens in different rows/columns. There are only $6$ such placements for each square. No one of them has tokens on "main" diagonals (see violet diagonals for the left square):

[image]

$10$ tokens are too few for such constructing.

Examples with $11$ tokens are shown by author of question.

---

**Part 2.** (thanks to **Gerry Myerson** for helpful comments)

Prove that **there are only eight placements of $11$ tokens** (all they are shown in the spoiler (see question text).

If we'll use $11$ tokens, then there are $3$ ways:

- to use columns with $1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4$ tokens;
- to use columns with $1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3$ tokens;
- to use columns with $1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2$ tokens.

First two cases require to place "rich" columns on the center of $7\times 8$ table (as above), and we'll need to place $7$ tokens in wide green area (as in part $1$). It is impossible (some of four "main" diagonals will be empty).

Third case: there can be
$\qquad$- $3$ "long" columns (like $a$, $b$: with distance between tokens $=5$); 
$\qquad$- or $2$ "long" and one "short" column (with  distance $\le 4$ between tokens).

If one of columns is "short", then $2$ "long" columns must be on the center (as above), and some of four "main" diagonals will be empty again.

So, we'll consider third case with $3$ "long" columns. Then third case requires to place one of $2$-token columns on the center ($4$th or $5$th column). WLOG, let it is column $b$ as $4$th column. Other possibilities are symmetric to this one (left-right mirroring, up-down mirroring, and both).

There are only $9$ such variants (where we need to place $5$ tokens in the green area):

these $3$ cases are impossible:
[image] $\quad$
[image] $\quad$
[image]

these $3$ cases are impossible too:
[image] $\quad$
[image] $\quad$
[image]

this one is impossible (at least $3$rd or $5$th column must have two tokens):
[image]

and **these $2$ cases are possible:**
[image] $\qquad$
[image]

These cases generate only $2$ possible placements (with column $b$ on the $4$th place).
Applying symmetries, we'll have all $8$ possible placements (shown by author).

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't answer the question, which was, can you prove, without exhaustive search, that OP has found all the 11-token solutions?

Comment: @Gerry, thank you. I've read question not carefully. I thought that there need to prove (without computations) that there are no $10$-tokens solutions. Now I completed my answer.

Comment: Do you not have to rule out 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4?

Comment: @Gerry, column with token in $1$st place must have $\ge 2$ tokens altogether, and column with token in $2$nd place must have $\ge 2$ tokens altogether, too. And these are different columns.

Comment: @Gerry, Oh, no. These columns can be as one. I need to correct my answer again. Thank you for useful notes!